# Can you mount heap onto zram

Tags: linux, memory, zram

I'm new to zram, and reading the documentation it looks like it mounts something similar to a filesystem under `/dev/zram<id>`.  If I understand correctly, anything stored here would be similar to tmpfs, except it would be swapped out to compressed ram.

I'm wondering if this concept can be applied to the heap of a program, such that any memory in the heap would be swapped to compressed ram instead of hdd?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that’s what [zswap](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/mm/zswap.html) does — it swaps to zram instead of a volume or file on disk. It’s set up by default in a number of distributions nowadays.